# Does Angular 1.5 save cookies to document?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have been scratching my head the whole day trying to understand how Angular ( not using ngCookies ) behaves when server responds with a Set-Cookie header.

I make a simple http post call using $http as shown below.

```
return $http.post('/api/login', credentials)
    .then(success)
    .catch(fail);
```

Note that I am not making a cross origin request, just making an api call to the origin server where html is served.

The server responds with

```
'Set-Cookie', 'sessionKey=abc123; Version=1;'
```

Subsequent api calls send cookie back as expected. The confusing bit is I can not see this cookie in browser console under resources-> cookies ( neither in Chrome nor Firefox).

Where is the cookie saved ? The official documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) states;

> Up until Angular 1.3, $cookies exposed properties that represented the current browser cookie values. In version 1.4, this behavior has changed, and $cookies now provides a standard api of getters, setters etc.

Does that mean it is not saving the cookies as document.cookie? Where are the cookies saved?

Comment: Are you sure they're working at all ? It says you need to require ngCookies in their docs.

Comment: @AndrewDonovan: Yes I am pretty sure, just double checked. Tried both with ngCookies and without it. I believe it is only needed if you need to access to the cookies. Or is it ?

Comment: ngCookies is their module for handling cookies. Setting and getting. This being said, i believe you need it, even just for reading. It also states in their doc: **Provides read/write access to browser's cookies.**. But this is just from reading, i have never used it myself.

Comment: Well i am quite confused about  it.

Comment: Reading their message, i think it translates simply to : in Ajs 1.3 and before, we offered usage of cookies as an object, cookie keys and values being properties of $cookie, and now it offers the standard cookie api that you could use in vanilla js. Someone correct me if i'm wrong